# How can i get specific tag?

Tags: wicket

I want to hide button of  component MessageDialog, so i have decided  to get tag of this button and call method hide but i don't know how to get specific tag of the element.
Here is code:

```
   public class TipOfTheDayDialog extends MessageDialog {
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TipOfTheDayDialog.class);

    public TipOfTheDayDialog(String id, String message) {
        super(id, "Совет дня", message, DialogButtons.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(IPartialPageRequestHandler handler, DialogButton button) {}


}
```

Comment: If this is com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.widget.dialog.MessageDialog, has good control from constructor. I cant imagine MessageDialog  totally without buttons, at least one must exist

Comment: Yes, i understand   Jacek Cz , i want to delete only close button , how can i do it maybe you can show some example with MessageDialog? Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi,

I think you first have to ensure that this button has an id attribute. If the button is a wicket component just call setMarkupId()

Answer (score 0):

Just hide it with CSS. Search a proper selector and set `display: none;`